# Calculating FPS With SDL 2.0

Tags: c++, sdl-2

```
#define FPS_INTERVAL 1.0 //seconds.

Uint32 fps_lasttime = SDL_GetTicks(); //the last recorded time.
Uint32 fps_current; //the current FPS.
Uint32 fps_frames = 0; //frames passed since the last recorded fps.

// you would initalise these in a main method, really.

void loop()
{
   //YOUR PAINTING STUFF HERE...
   //********//

   fps_frames++;
   if (fps_lasttime < SDL_GetTicks() - FPS_INTERVAL*1000)
   {
      fps_lasttime = SDL_GetTicks();
      fps_current = fps_frames;
      fps_frames = 0;
   }
}
```

I took the code above from:
http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Average_FPS_Measurement

I understand the code but the FPS_INTERVAL confuses me because I can't really understand why it's needed in the if statement. Can someone explain this?

And also do I have to use Uint32 or would any int do the job and why?

Answer (score 1):

`SDL_GetTicks()` returns number of milliseconds; `FPS_INTERVAL` specifies number of seconds (here - 1) to count the frames; it is multiplied by 1,000 to get number of milliseconds.

Re: Uint32 - that is what `SDL_GetTicks()` returns. What other type would you use, and why?

Comment: I saw in a youtube tutorial the programmer use just 'int' not the 'uint32'

Comment: If a "programmer" decides to mix signed and unsigned values, with potentially different sizes, he takes responsibility for resolving all conflicts. WHY would you want that?

Comment: I don't plan to use any other type .I just wondered why in that tutorial the programmer used int but anyways thanks for the help!

Comment: There might be multiple reasons: (1) Lazy (int is a shorter word than Uint32); (2) Ignorant to a differences between these types; (3) Overly confident that the only values possible in this scenario are the same in Uint32 and in int representations.